# What is the best practice to receive application logs of my app in an error case?

Tags: android

I want to enable some error report in my app, for that I am searching for a way which works in devices higher than api level 8

My current implementation does not work on a Android 4.1.1 device, there is no action when the user presses the error report button. On a device 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0.4 it shows the different email options.

The action method in my code looks like this

```
public void startSendErrorAction(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType( "text/plain" );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"my@email.de" });
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "PDiXAttach LogReport from " + DateTime.now());
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getLogContent() );

    startActivity(intent);        

}
```

The getLogContent Method retrieves the application log entries with the logcat -d option. But it currently does not work on the device

```
Hersteller: samsung
Modell: GT-N7100
Marke: samsung
Version: 4.1.1 (REL)
```

Here the getLogContent-Method

```
public String getLogContent() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String separator = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -d" );
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                                            new InputStreamReader( process.getInputStream() ) );
        String line;
        while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            sb.append( line );
            sb.append( separator );
        }
        Log.d( TAG, "retrieve log content size is " + sb.length() );

    }
    catch( IOException e ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "error while retrieving logfile of application" + e.getMessage() );
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Does someone know what might be the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra) does an excellent job of what you want, and works on all android versions that I've bothered using it on. It provides way more details than the Google Play reports, and can be very helpful in tracking down bugs remotely.

Comment: Is it possible to use that ACRA to trigger an report with a button in my app or will it only be active when a application crash occurs? DO you hava an example for a manual trigger with ACRA?

Comment: @AlPhaba That is unrelated to your current question, but [this](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Sending_reports_for_caught_exceptions) should help.

Comment: Thanks that was what I am looking for. Now testing on the problem device

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  [Alogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en)  for runTime crashes.